# Can't read input.txt file correctly using a multithreaded scraper in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, file-io, python-multithreading

I use the input file `IG#Input.txt` which contains:

```
qwdlab
qwdwe
```

The script would get all usernames from these Instagram hashtags but it's not working if there is more than 1 hashtag in the input.txt file. What do I need to change to make it work correctly along with the multithreading?

The script workflow would be like:

- Reading hashtags/lines from input.txt file
- Scraping them multithreaded
- Printing the output into the `outputIG.txt` file

Code:

```
import threading
from instaloader import Instaloader
import time

#Classes for threading
class LockedIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, it):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.it = it.__iter__()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            return self.it.__next__()
        finally:
            self.lock.release()

# input()
input = open("IG#Input.txt","r",encoding='utf-8')
HASHTAG = input.read()
p = HASHTAG.split('\n')
PROFILE = p[:]

posts = Instaloader(sleep=False).get_hashtag_posts(HASHTAG)
posts = LockedIterator(posts)

output = open("outputIG.txt","w+")

# Main
def worker():
    for ind in range(len(PROFILE)):
        pro = PROFILE[ind]
        try:
            for post in posts:
                print(post.owner_username)
                output.write(post.owner_username + '\n')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise  

#Start Threading
threads = []

for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

output.close()
```

Comment: could you try to explain better what your problem is.

What happens? What would you expect to happen instead?
DO you have any outputs / error messages you can share with us?

Comment: @gelonida The script shoud scrape all usernames from the instagram hashtags in the input file and print them to the output file. The current error message is "404 Not Found" because it's formatting all hashtags inside the input file as one url (eg. explore/tags/qwdlabqwdwe/: ) instead of looping each one by one. My attempts to solve this always result in a wrong multithreading loop.